Importing RNA seq raw counts as nsorted.htseq.counts files in R
I have a list of RNAseq raw counts data (one file for each sample) in directory with extension nsorted.htseq.counts. I would like to import all of them and to combine in one dataset. How can I do it?
Some of my tries:
data<- list.files(path ="C:/Users/Korisnik/Desktop/Dataset/ pattern = "*nsorted.htseq.counts", full.names = TRUE)
readHTSeqFile(data)
